# Print students in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to have the user type in the last name and first name of a student in an array so that I can call the student information and use it in a grade book.

The `Student` class has a method called `Student(String last_name, String first_name)`

I cannot figure out how to make it print students in a list such as:

```
last name, first name
last name, first name
```

Here is my program so far:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("--------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Gradebook Program");
    System.out.println("--------------------------------");
    System.out.println();

    students = GetNumberOfStudents();

    //Allocate space for student information
    Student student[] = new Student[students];

    for (int i = 0; i < students; i++)
    {
        System.out.println("Student #" + (i+1));

        System.out.print("\tEnter last name: ");
        student[i] = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.print("\tEnter first name: ");
        student[i] = scan.nextLine();
    }

    System.out.println(student[i]);
```

Comment: What do you think this does:  `student[i] = scan.nextLine();`? What happens when you do it twice?

Comment: You can't access i outside of the loop.

Comment: All you do is take information, but you're not creating a new `Student` object. This won't even compile. `student[]` is an array of `Student` objects, `scan.nextLine()` returns a `String`.

Comment: show the student class too please.

Comment: all these `Student` homeworks... :)

Comment: I don't have the student class, i only have methods, but here they are...

Comment: A student object has a first name, a last name, and 3 test scores.
Available methods in the student class
Student ()
Constructor: creates a new student object
Student (String last_name, String first_name)
Constructor: creates a new student object with given first and last name
String firstName()
Returns student’s first name
String lastName()
Returns student’s last name
int testScore(int index)
Returns student’s score on specified test (index of 0, 1, or 2)
double testAverage()
Returns average of all 3 student test scores
int maxTestScore()
Returns student’s highest test score

Comment: boolean isPassing()
Returns true if student is passing; otherwise returns false
void setTestScore(int index, int score)
Sets student’s score on specified test (based on index); sets to value of score

Comment: I have attempted several ways and have been trying to do this all night. I know this won't compile, but I just need help with this and the rest of the program I can complete.

Answer (score 1):

I expect we would need to see the definition of Student, you have given the constructor but not the getters/setters.

I would expect the printing code to look something like

```
for (Student s : student) {
    System.out.println(s.getLastName() + "," + s.getFirstName());
}
```

You are also not initialising your Student objects correctly.
Inside the loop you have written I would expect to see

```
new Student(lastname, firstname);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a soltuion with a student class which looks like in your description.

```
package test; //change to your package name

import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Student{

    private String m_LastName;
    private String m_FirstName;
    private int[] TestScores = new int[3];

    //Constructor
    public Student(String last, String first) {
        m_LastName = last;
        m_FirstName = first;
    }

    //returns firstname
    public String firstName() {
        return m_FirstName;
    }

    //returns lastname
    public String lastName() {
        return m_LastName;
    }

    //set a test score at a given index
    public void setTestScore(int index, int score) {
        TestScores[index] = score;
    }

    //returns test score at a given index
    public int testScore(int index) {
        return TestScores[index];
    }

    //returns testscores average
    public double testAverage() {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i<TestScores.length; i++) {
            sum += TestScores[i];
        }
        return sum/TestScores.length;
    }

    //returns students highest test score
    public int maxTestScore() {
        //sort the array
        for(int i = 0; i<TestScores.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j<TestScores.length; j++) {
                if(TestScores[i]<TestScores[j]) {
                    int buffer;
                    buffer = TestScores[i];
                    TestScores[i] = TestScores[j];
                    TestScores[j] = buffer;
                }   
            }
        }
        return TestScores[TestScores.length-1];
    }


    public boolean isPassing() {
        //TODO: when hes passing?
        return true;
    }




    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Welcome to the Gradebook Program");
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");
        System.out.println();

        /**
         * dont know where you declare the students variable
         * and how the getnumberofstudents function looks like
         * 
         * students = GetNumberOfStudents();  
         */  
        int students = 1;

        List<Student> StudentList = new ArrayList<>();   //creat a list which can store student objects

        for (int i = 0; i < students; i++)
        {

            System.out.println("Student #" + (i+1));

            System.out.print("\tEnter last name: ");
            String lastname = scan.nextLine();        //store lastname in a variable 
            System.out.print("\tEnter first name: ");
            String firstname = scan.nextLine();       //store firstname in a variable 

            Student student = new Student(lastname, firstname);  //creat new student object with the last and firstname
            StudentList.add(student);                            //add it to the student list
        }


        //print out all students first and lastnames. here you can add the other data you want to print.
        for (int i = 0; i < students; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("List of all Students:");
            System.out.println("Firstname:"+StudentList.get(i).firstName()+" Lastname:"+StudentList.get(i).lastName());
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I just have this error.....java:24: error: cannot find symbolList<Student> StudentList = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: This was an example my teacher gave to show how to get info from the Student class......//Demonstrate constructors
  Student student1 = new Student();
  Student student2 = new Student("Smith", "Terry");

  //Store 3 test scores for each student
  student1.setTestScore(0,85);
  student1.setTestScore(1,90);
  student1.setTestScore(2,78);

  student2.setTestScore(0,79);
  student2.setTestScore(1,98);
  student2.setTestScore(2,91);

  //Display each student object
  System.out.println("Student 1: " + student1);
  System.out.println("Student 2: " + student2);

Comment: the "cannot find symbol" error occurs because the compiler cant find a certain part of your code. for example the student class. did you import the student class and List + ArrayList? Press Strg+Shift+O to organize your imports.

Comment: i add the whole code with a students class i have written. it looks like the student class you described. this code works.